# overwriting column with fputcsv

Tags: php, csv

I want to parse, process and then overwrite only 1 specific column in a csv file, I'm fine with the first two steps but am having issues with the third. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$row = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$get = $data[2];
$uc = ucwords(strtoupper($get));
echo $uc;
}
?>
```

That displays fine, I just need the processed content to be written back into it's original column. I know this is done with fputcsv, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $uc, ",");
fclose($fp);
```

That just wipes the entire file. Same thing when using fwrite. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that both functions work for `lines`, not for the whole file.

So you will have to rebuild it when you write out, something like:

```
<?php
$list = array (
   'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
   '123,456,789',
   '"aaa","bbb"'
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $line) {
   fputcsv($fp, split(',', $line));
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Untested

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("data.csv", "r");
$row = 1;
$list=array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $data[2] = ucwords(strtoupper($data[2]));
    $list[]=$data; // collect lines
}
fclose($fh);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $line) {
   fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```